# Is it possible to get and activate a SIM card after 23:00 in Tallinn (Airport)?

Tags: cellphones, estonia, tallinn

I'm going to arrive at Tallinn Airport but the flight is scheduled to arrive at 23:00. According to [Prepaid Data SIM Card Wiki on Estonia](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Estonia):

> Prepaid SIM cards called Kõnekaart are available at newsstands, kiosks, supermarkets, other outlets and the shops of the providers. No ID or registration is necessary. Like other Baltic states, Estonia offers low prices for data compared to the rest of Europe.

So I wish I could get it after 23:00.

However, I wonder where I can buy and activate a SIM card in Tallinn, after 23:00. I must contract it in order to get to my room at AirBnB.

Is it possible to buy it at the airport after 23:00? Or is it better to go to the city center and buy it (and are supermarkets still open before midnight?)?

Comment: Do you really need a SIM-card to get access to your room?  Can't you use some wifi somewhere?

Comment: @gerrit I never trust public Wi-Fi (and in my experience no country offers decent public Wi-Fi).

Comment: How decent does it need to be, presumably you just need to sign in to your airbnb account to check if there is a message?  That's what I ended up doing coming from Canada to an airbnb in the UK.  You can probably do that at the airport.

Comment: @gerrit AirBnB messages and Google map. In most cases the public Wi-Fi doesn’t connect in the first place (or no signal), and I would have to roam around to get a signal with my big baggage.

Comment: "(and in my experience no country offers decent public Wi-Fi)" You haven't traveled enough I guess... Besides, if you connect to web sites that use SSL, and both Airbnb and Google do, you're safe...

Comment: In order not to sleep on bench in park, you'll need to activate this SIM card as well. I don't know how it is in Estonia, but in Germany you need an internet connection for it (so you need an extra internet connection anywhere). I hope you'll be fine, but your travel plans are really extreme for me.

Comment: If you're coming from an EU country it is pretty much pointless to buy a local SIM card since roaming is now free.

Comment: I don't have a SIM card from one of EU countries...

Comment: @dda Which cities, say in top 50 most popular tourist destinations, provide the decent public Wi-Fi? It is true that I have not traveled enough but in my experience to travel to about 20 cities in Asia and Europe, no city provided decent public Wi-Fi (in most cases there is no signal, and even if it is, the signal is too weak and/or it is limited to specifc places such as near metro stations, or the registration is not written in English and thus pretty stressful to even connect to)...

Comment: Seoul (or any city in Korea), Tokyo (and most larger cities), HK, Singapore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a kiosk open until 24:00 at the airport](https://www.tallinn-airport.ee/en/shops/) (but it is until 21:30 on Sunday), and you can buy a SIM card there.

It is located at the right side from the exit gate. However, only Tele2 prepaid SIM card is sold, and only one plan (7 days, 5GB for about 3.5 to 3.7 Euro) is available.

You don't need to get through a bothering verification process; just insert the SIM card, type in unlocking number, and you can immediately use 4G/LTE mobile network.